# The way in which or by which?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to say something very weird, but I'm not sure if any of these sentences makes sense:

'Recursion is the way in which a function is specified in terms of itself'
or
'Recursion is a way by which a function is specified in terms of itself'

Comment: I'd say neither is appropriate. [mathematical usage:] 'Recursion is the practice of defining numbers, expressions, etc. in terms of [some of] the numbers, expressions, etc. that come before them in a series.' eg f(n+1) = g[f(n)].

Comment: There's a good question hidden here; a pair of less contentious examples would be good. 'The way _in which_' has been covered before (it is used when detailing how things work, or how this is achieved). 'The way _by which_' is restricted to how something is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

If there are other ways by which "a function is specified in terms of itself", then you should use **a** or **one**. If it is the only way, or the preferred way, then use **the**. If you want to modify way, e.g. *best*, use *the*.

> Dictionary: [A way](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/dictionary-a-way-to-define-an-argument/2013/02/03/7bc28cb6-6ca1-11e2-ada0-5ca5fa7ebe79_story.html) to define an argument - The Washington Post
>
> One problem with these studies, however, is [the way](http://books.google.com/books?id=HqfCgX7zOcwC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22is+the+way+to+define%22&source=bl&ots=12ClmiRw81&sig=0k_0QjVie_3Y_rySDI1LToik-H4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nL0TU5z3J6q_0QHVw4LoCg&ved=0CGgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20the%20way%20to%20define%22&f=false)) to define, and then to quantify, the traditional Med diet. - Artemis P. Simopoulos
>
> Whether or not street protest is **the best way** to get to where they want to go, the method has been its own best medicine. - The Bangkok Post

Comment: Agreed 100%. But perhaps you could address why *by which* is not preferred.

Comment: @DavidM - I would use *by which* only in formal writing, not informal. *A way* or *the way* is extremely common in informal writing and 'normal' speech.

Comment: I would say that the function _y = xˣ_ is defined in terms of itself, in at least one sense of that phrase, though it isn't a recursive function. Note that it's prior values of a recursive function that determine the next value, so there is at least one more dimension to take into consideration.

Comment: Is it defined by recursion or using recursion? I'd argue the latter, which is why "by" may not be appropriate.

Comment: @StuartF - If you're responding to John Lawler, you need to address the comment to him by using @(name).